# Perl hash usage

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to create a hash from the following sample file:

---

Sample File:

```
#NewName              OldName
Axc.Sx2.1_Axc.Wx2.1  1BDER
Axc.Sx2.1_Axc.Wx2.1  1ADER
Axc.Wxx.5            1DDER
```

---

The keys of the hash should be `newName` and the values should be the `oldname`. The code below works quite well for lines which are unique in the file:

```
while (<$mapF>) {
    chomp $_;
    next if /^\s*(#.*)?$/;
    next if /^\s+.*$/;
    ##latestRuleName OldRuleName
    if ( $_ =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/gi ) {
        # create list and apped $2
        $mapHash{$1} = $2;
    }
}

foreach ( keys %mapHash ) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

But for the duplicate entries( like row 1 and row2 in above snippet ), the first entry gets overwritten by the second one. hence, I get only two entries in my hash:

```
Axc.Sx2.1_Axc.Wx2.1  
Axc.Wxx.5
```

Is there a way to get all three entries in the mapHash?

Answer (score 4):

Keys in a hash must be unique. You can store several values for each key, though, it's called the Hash of Arrays or HoA. It means an array reference is stored at each key:

```
push @{ $mapHash{$1} }, $2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot choroba. How to access these hashesh of array now?

Comment: @DiveshRastogi: `$mapHash{key}` will be an array reference, so you can subscript it with `$mapHash{key}[0]` etc., or dereference it to get the full array: `@{ $mapHash{key} }`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Choroba :) it's all up now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Tie::Hash::MultiValue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::MultiValue) CPAN module, which stores multiple values per key

Comment: Thanks a lot Miguel Prz for pointing the CPAN: module. I'll definitely use that in the future.